# How do I add objects to an array that is inside an array?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add an object to an array that is inside an array.

[image: Screens]

Here is my storyboard. Screen A is a simple tableView containing an array with object A, Screen B adds new objects to screen A. Each object A contains an array with detail (object B), these details are shown in screen C and you add details to object A in screen D.

[image: Arrays]

So my model is as you can see above. I got Array A containing object A, each object contains Array B containing object B. Both my arrays are Mutable.

Object A = budget
Object B = item

I can not figure out how to add object B to array B.

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(AddItemViewController *)controller didFinishAddingItem:(Item *)item

    int newRowIndex = [self.budgets.items count];
[self.dataModel.budgetsList addObjectFromArray:item];

NSLog(@"Item with name %@ added", item.name);

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is what I am doing so fare. My problem here is that I am adding item (object B) into budget array (array A). :/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here or what your problem is. Your is a little confusing f.e. `addObjectFromArray:` the name implies that it would add an object **from another** array to `budgetsList`, yet you're passing a single object `item` to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this:

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
```

You are mixing Presentation with data. What you need here is get the object element (the array in your case) that this indexpath corresponds to. As per the Table view design pattern, every table view reads its cells from an underlying collection of data objects. Have you defined this object (most preferably in separate objective-c .m and .h files)?

As for adding array into another array, NSArray just expects NSObject as element, so it is pretty straight-forward to add one into another.

```
NSArray *arrayB = [[NSArray alloc] init]; //any other initialization is good as well
NSArray *arrayA= [NSArray arrayWithObject:arrayB];
```

The above code is valid for any pair of NSArrays in your code.

Comment: I do not want to add an array to an other array. I want to add an object to an array who is inside an other array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an object to Array B, then Use:

```
[[[array A objectAtIndex:indexPath] arrayB] addObject:yourObject];
```

Or you can use (this is an expansion of above code):

```
ObjectA *temp = [array A objectAtIndex:indexPath];

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [temp arrayB];

[tempArray addObject:yourObject];
```

Comment: Yep I can not really make this work. Here is what I am trying so fare  `int newRowIndex = [self.budgets.items count];
[[[self.dataModel.budgetsList objectAtIndex:newRowIndex] items] addObject:item];` But I now get an error saying: "No visible @interface for NSArray declares the selector addObject" I am not sure what this means .. :/

Comment: @Opstrup: you cannot add object to `NSArray` using `addObject` method. Change the array type to `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Both my arrays are NSMutableArray

Comment: @Opstrup: then this error message (No visible @ interface for NSArray declares the selector addObject) won't occur

Comment: I will look my code over again and see if I can figure out where the problem is. I have also found some documentation on index paths and path through nested array. You know apple's documentation is pretty good :) Thank you for your time and help I will maybe PM you if I can not make it to work if that is okay ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cast your object B to `Item` then do

```
[self.dataModel.budgetList replaceObjectAtIndex:11 withObject:(Item)item];
```

This code assume that you want to replace the existing object inside A and the the index is 11. If you want to add you just use `insertObjectAtIndex: withObject:`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by cast my object B to item? Can you link any documentation about casting or maybe explain what that means? This is my first app, sorry for an inconvenience :(